# How to add image along with some other data in a table cell using php

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I'm designing a calendar using `javascript` and what to add some icon on some particular date to show what special on that day, but i used echo to print the current day in each `table cell`, meanwhile i need to add those icons on relevant date.

Send me some sample coding

```
for ($i=1; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {

 if (($i % 7) == 1 ) 
    echo "<tr>";

if ($i < $startday)
{ 
    echo "<td></td>";
    continue;
};
$current_day = $i - $startday + 1;
if(in_array($cYear."-".$cMonth."-".$current_day,$unavailable))
{
     echo "<td>". $current_day . "</div></td>";

}
else
{
    echo "<td class=\"available\">". $current_day ." </td>";

}
}
if (($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "</tr>";
```

}
?>

Just using echo i'm displaying the date ie from 1 to 31 but i need to add some icons along with some specific date...

Comment: You question is unclear. Can you please provide some sample code to help explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either echo  tag, or if you want the picture on background, you will create the class reffering to the background and you will echo the class along with  tag.

Comment: Thank u sir, i done it successfully